# emberjs place limit and offset metadata into headers within RESTadapter for a findQuery

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How does one grab the `offset` and `limit` (or any query for that matter) provided in a `find()` issued from a route as follows

```
this.store.find('person', {offset: 0, limit:10});
```

and then grab those two values in an adapter to push them as headers (opposed to the body)

im checking out the [docs regarding metadata](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/handling-metadata/) and see mention of `this.store.metadataFor("person");`

plus the example in the [docs re RESTAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_headers-customization) that mentions using an injector for an authtoken.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  headers: function() {
    return {
      "API_KEY": this.get("session.authToken"),
      "ANOTHER_HEADER": "Some header value"
    };
  }.property("session.authToken")
});
```

how would one do a similar 'injector' on a model (versus session).

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

   headers: function() {
      var limit = this.get("person.limit");    // injector style ??
      //var limit = this.store.metadataFor("person"); //but no ref to store
      return {"limit": limit};
   }.property("person.limit"),
```

"the session object has been injected into an adapter by Ember's container." seems to be part of the mystery sauce.

tia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the properties inside an object to query the store, they eventually end up in the `findQuery` method which by default looks like this (see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.14.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L331)):

```
findQuery: function(store, type, query) {
  return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey), 'GET', { data: query });
},
```

The `query` gets passed in as request parameters. I am guessing you can override this method inside the adapter and pass them in as headers instead.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  findQuery: function(store, type, query) {
    console.log("OFFSET: " + query.offset);
    console.log("LIMIT: " + query.limit);

    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey), 'GET', { headers: query });
  },
});
```

`this.ajax` method used by the adapter calls the jQuery's `ajax` method as you can see over [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.14.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L809). According to jQuery's documentation, you can pass in `headers` as an object (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). Therefore, in you case you can just replace `data` with `headers` and you will be done.

The output from Chrome's debugger confirms that the request headers are actually being sent:

[image]

See the following [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xurunu/2/edit)

Comment: so override the findQuery method in an adapter.  that makes sense. but how to then push it into headers (or the header method). ill look into this.ajax in the meantime. thnx

Comment: the { headers: query } suggestion does work as described.  i was seeking an 'injected object' but this is not so bad. cheers.